# Problems with legacy ASP version 2 Website

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

We have an old website we are trying to resurrect .  Everything works except this one page

> ERROR: -2147217900 - [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   Procedure or function sp_XXXX_XXX_Order_Information has too many arguments specified.
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>   Object required: 'openRecordSet(...)'
>    /admin/XXXX/order_info.asp, line 11

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/scripts/functions.asp"-->
<%
    SetUserLevel(" 2 3 8 ")

    QSON        = prepareSQL(Request.QueryString("ON"))

    If (Len(QSON) = 0) Then Response.Redirect("/admin/customercare/")

    Dim objConnection, objRecordset, BGColor, CC_Count, PP_Count, Ticket_Count, Tracking_Count, History_Type, User_Notes, UID, Trouble_Tickets
    Set objConnection   = openConnectionAdmin()
    Set objRecordset    = openRecordset("EXEC sp_XXXX_XXX_Order_Information '" & QSON & "'," & Session("User_ID"), objConnection)   

    If (objRecordset.State = 0) Then
        Set objRecordset    = Nothing
        Set objConnection   = Nothing
        Response.Write("Order Not Found")
        Response.End
    End If

    UID     = objRecordset("User_ID")
    CC_Count    = objRecordset("Credit_Card_Count")
    VS_Count    = objRecordset("VeriSign_Count")
    PP_Count    = objRecordset("PayPal_Count")
    Tracking_Count  = objRecordset("Tracking_Numbers")
    User_Notes  = objRecordset("User_Notes")
    Trouble_Tickets = objRecordset("Trouble_Tickets")
    History_Type    = objRecordset("History_Type_ID")

    Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

    If (objRecordset.State = 0) Then
        Set objRecordset    = Nothing
        Set objConnection   = Nothing
        Response.Write("Order Not Found")
        Response.End
    End If
%>
<HTML>
<TITLE>iXXXX.XX- Customer Care Center</TITLE>
<HEAD>
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="/admin/subpage.css" TYPE="text/css">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function popUp2(url, height, width) 
{
  sealWin=window.open(url,"win",'height=' + height + ',width=' + width + ', toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
  self.name = "mainWin";
}

function charcount()
{
    if (DH)
    {
        cr = fd('cd',0)
        ct = document.Note.Note_Detail.value.length;

        if (ct > 2000) cr.innerHTML = '<FONT COLOR="#660000">' + ct + ' characters (of 2000)</FONT>';
        else if (ct > 1800) cr.innerHTML = '<FONT COLOR="#666600">' + ct + ' characters (of 2000)</FONT>';
        else cr.innerHTML = ct + ' characters (of 2000)';
    }
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>
<!--#include virtual="/admin/includes/info_popin.inc"-->
<!--#include virtual="/admin/includes/edit_fields.inc"-->
<DIV ID="info_popin" CLASS="tip"><TABLE><div style='position:relative;bottom:75px;left:150px;padding:1px;background-color:#EEEEEE; font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt;'></div></TABLE></DIV>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
    <!--#include virtual="/admin/includes/customercareheader.inc"-->

    <P>
    <FORM NAME="Shipping" METHOD=POST ACTION="order_shipping_update.asp">
    <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=ON VALUE="<%= QSON %>">
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH COLSPAN="3">Order #<%= QSON %><BR><BR></TH></TR>
    <TR>
    <%
        Response.Write objRecordset("TableRow")
        Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()
    %>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN="3" ALIGN="CENTER"><DIV ID=sd STYLE="display: none;"><INPUT TYPE=BUTTON ONCLICK="document.Shipping.reset(); history.go();" VALUE="Cancel"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Update"></DIV></TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    </P>

    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Product</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Dosage</TH><TH>Count</TH><TH>Quantity</TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Amount</TH></TR>
    <%
        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
            Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    </TABLE>
    </P>


    <%
        If (Tracking_Count > 0 And (History_Type = 13 OR History_Type = 24)) Then
    %>
    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Billed</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">UPS Tracking Number</TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Notification Email</TH></TR>
    <%
        Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
            Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    </TABLE>
    </P>
    <%
        End If
    %>



    <%
        If (PP_Count > 0) Then
    %>
    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Date</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">PayPal Account</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Status</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT"><BR></TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Amount</TH></TR>
    <%
        Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
            Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    </TABLE>
    </P>
    <%
        End If
    %>



    <%
        If (CC_Count > 0) Then
    %>
    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Date</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT"><NOBR>Credit Response</NOBR></TH><TH ALIGN="CENTER" COLSPAN="2">AVS and CVV2 Responses</TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Amount</TH></TR>
    <%
        Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
            Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    </TABLE>
    </P>
    <%
        End If
    %>



    <%
        If (VS_Count > 0) Then
    %>
    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Date</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Reference</TH><TH ALIGN="CENTER">Result</TH><TH>AVS</TH><TH>Type</TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Amount</TH></TR>
    <%
        Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
            Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN="6" ALIGN="CENTER" STYLE="font-size: 8pt;">Only transactions in <B>BOLD</B> have been accepted and processed.</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    </P>
    <%
        End If
    %>



    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH COLSPAN="2">Order Questionnaire</TH></TR>
    <%
        Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
            Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    </TABLE>
    </P>


    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH COLSPAN="3">Notes Created on this Order</TH></TR>
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Date</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Short Detail</TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Author</TH></TR>
    <%
        If (User_Notes > 0) Then

            Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

            Do Until objRecordset.EOF
                BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
                Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
                objRecordset.MoveNext
            Loop
        Else
            Response.Write "<TR><TD COLSPAN=""3"" ALIGN=""CENTER"">There are no notes on this account.</TD></TR>"
        End If
    %>
    <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="3">
        <DIV ID=no ALIGN="CENTER" STYLE="font-size: 8pt;"><A ONCLICK="edit('no','ns');"><BR>Add Note to this Client</A></DIV>
        <DIV ID=noe STYLE="display: none;">
            <FORM NAME="Note" METHOD=POST ACTION="customer_add_note.asp">
            <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=UID VALUE="<%= UID %>">
            <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=ON VALUE="<%= QSON %>">
            <BR><B>Adding Note</B>:<BR>
            <TEXTAREA NAME="Note_Detail" COLS=50 ROWS=5 STYLE="width:580px;" ONKEYUP="charcount();"></TEXTAREA>
            <DIV ID=cd ALIGN="CENTER">0 characters (of 2000)</DIV>
            <DIV ID=ns  STYLE="display: none;" ALIGN="CENTER"><INPUT TYPE=RESET VALUE="Clear"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Add Note"><BR><BR></DIV>
            </FORM>
        </DIV>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </P>



    <%
    If (Session("User_Level") = " 1 ") Then
    %>
    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR>
    <TD>
        <DIV ID=de ALIGN="CENTER" STYLE="font-size: 8pt;"><A ONCLICK="edit('de','ds');">Send Pre-made Decline to this Client</A></DIV>
        <DIV ID=dee STYLE="display: none;">
            <CENTER><B>Send Decline</B></CENTER>

            <FORM NAME="DeclineLetter" METHOD=POST ACTION="customer_send_decline.asp">
            <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=ON VALUE="<%= QSON %>">

            <P STYLE="margin-left: 30px;">
            <%
                Dim objDeclineRecordset
                Set objDeclineRecordset = openRecordset("EXEC sp_Doctor_Get_Declines", objConnection)
                Do Until objDeclineRecordset.EOF
                    Response.Write objDeclineRecordset("OptionRow") & vbCrLf
                    objDeclineRecordset.MoveNext
                Loop
                objDeclineRecordset.Close
                Set objDeclineRecordset = Nothing
            %>

            </P>

            <DIV ID=ds  STYLE="display: none;" ALIGN="CENTER"><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Send"><BR><BR></DIV>
            </FORM>
        </DIV>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </P>
    <%
    End If
    %>



    <P>
    <TABLE WIDTH="600" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="CCListTbl">
    <TR><TH COLSPAN="4">Trouble Tickets on this Order</TH></TR>
    <TR><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Date</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Ticket</TH><TH ALIGN="LEFT">Last Short Detail</TH><TH></TH><TH ALIGN="RIGHT">Last Author</TH></TR>
    <%
        If (Trouble_Tickets > 0) Then

            Set objRecordset = objRecordset.NextRecordset()

            Do Until objRecordset.EOF
                BGColor = IIF(BGColor = "DEDEDE", "EFEFEF", "DEDEDE")
                Response.Write "<TR BGCOLOR=""" & BGColor & """>" & objRecordset("TableRow") & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
                objRecordset.MoveNext
            Loop
        Else
            Response.Write "<TR><TD COLSPAN=""5"" ALIGN=""CENTER"">There are no trouble tickets on this order.</TD></TR>"
        End If
    %>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN="5" ALIGN="CENTER"><BR><A HREF="trouble/add_ticket.asp?UID=<%= UID %>&ON=<%= QSON %>" STYLE="font-size: 8pt;">Create a New Trouble Ticket for this Order</A></TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    </P>
    <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>

</BODY>
</HTML>
<%
    objRecordset.Close
    Set objRecordset    = Nothing
    Set objConnection   = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: here is some of the stored proc

Comment: Where is the stored proc?

Comment: Check that you're actually opening something with `openConnectionAdmin`.

Comment: @Paul SQL Server complains about the number of arguments that have been specified to the `sp_XXXX_XXX_Order_Information` stored procedure so the OP must have a valid `ADODB.Connection`.

Comment: Good point, @Lankymart.

Comment: thank you for all your help.  the stored proc is very long and i am trying to figure out how to attach

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157263/problems-with-legacy-asp-version-2-website-part-2-with-stored-proc                     this is the stored proc

Comment: @BonnieAllard Do not post duplicate questions, if the stored procedure is too long just post the definition showing the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So, your error states that there are too many arguments for the call to the stored procedure on this line:

```
EXEC sp_XXXX_XXX_Order_Information '" & QSON & "'," & Session("User_ID")
```

I would cross-check the stored procedure `sp_XXXX_XXX_Order_Information` in the database. It should accept 2 variables for `QSON` and `UserID` (or similar).

Additionally I would check that you (a) have values for `QSON` and `Session("User_ID")` on that line that calls the stored procedure. 
I would also check that the values of both of those variables don't need to be sanitized. For example, if `QSON` has the value `test','ing` it could inadvertently add another variable. You need to escape these.

Comment: depends what's in the `openRecordset` function but yes. I have to say, I don't miss Classic ASP!

Comment: I'd imagine something probably a long the lines of `Set openRecordset = conn.Execute(sql)` which is not good at all.